# How should I rig/paint identical bones efficiently?

Tags: weight-painting

I have multiple identical 'cars' which should have identical weight paints and should form a line as part of one possessed-roller-coaster-monster.
[image]

What is the best way/order to tackle this? Should I:

-Add a bone to one car, paint the car, then merge the bones/cars? How would I merge the bones into one armature properly?

-Paste all the cars, make all the bones at once, paint one car and copy the paints to the other car? How would I copy the paints?

-Something else?

Assume I'm somewhat familiar but not too experienced with weight painting and haven't done it in a while.

Comment: What about parenting With Empty Group then assign each car to the correct vertex group?